# But not everyone realizes that fact. Vs But not everyone realizes this fact

Tags: word-usage, demonstrative, demonstrative-pronouns

> Small churches aren’t just smaller versions of big churches. They have
>   unique gifts, challenges and methods of operation.
>
> But not everyone realizes ***that*** fact. Including some small church
>   pastors.
>
> ***This*** often leads to frustration when we go to ministerial conferences
>   or read pastoral books.

Why does the writer say ***that*** not ***this***?

My guess is  because he is speaking about a *fact* and not his own thought.

Or because the writer refers to something mentioned before not something he is speaking about. I am not sure.

And why he use ***this*** not ***that*** in the following paragraph ?

Thank you

Comment: I think the _this_ could be changed to a _that_ or vice versa and the passage would still make sense. It's somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This** and **that** are deictic, expressing the speaker's sense of nearness to or distance from the thing being "pointed at". The distance can be literal physical distance or "mental distance".

When a speaker says "this", he is near the thing, and if it is not a thing but an idea, it can be as though he were *proffering* the idea for consideration. The nature of the "mental closeness" can vary. It may be an idea currently under consideration and being debated at this moment, and the nearness may be no more than the fact that the speaker is taking part in the discussion:

> This idea is a good one.
>
> This idea is a bad one.

When a speaker says "that", he is some distance from the thing (e.g. "that thing over there"), and if it is not a thing but an idea, the speaker is *referring* to the idea.

Comment: I wouldn't mind betting that if we could analyse all the times a chairman of a meeting has ever guillotined debate by saying *this/that idea is a good/bad one*, we'd find ***this + good*** and ***that + bad*** occurred far more often that ***this + bad*** and ***that + good***. One always likes to distance oneself from bad things.

Comment: Thank TRomano, it is much clear now. But let me ask you plz after we have understood that the writer is mentally distance when using ***that***. What does the writer mentally distance from ? From the *fact*? Does that mean that he is not going to discuss the fact or delve into its details ? Or does he simply think it is not his idea ?

Comment: @Gamal Thomas: The "mental distance" expressed by **that** might be no more than a *reference* to the idea as one mentioned earlier or brought up earlier in some other way. To say **that idea** or simply **that** is not necessarily a distancing of oneself from the idea or a rejection of it, as one might wrongly infer from the comment by FumbleFingers above.  One could easily say "**That's** the place for me!" after hearing a destination proposal for a trip, and then after one has arrived there: "I love this place. **This** is the place for me!" The same is true with an idea.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, thank you, I can guess now that the speaker was saying "that fact" to mean that fact that everyone forget about or not realize = "mental far distance" But he says "This often leads.." because  he was speaking about his own idea  now between his own hands and he needs everyone to involve and discuss, it is something NEAR everyone. ... Am I right here?